# Select interval linq

Tags: c#, linq

Is there some way with `LINQ` to select certain numbers with shortcut criteria.
Like this:
I have numbers from `1 to 10000`.
My criteria is `(4012..4190|4229)`, meaning take numbers between `4012 to 4190` and number `4229`:

```
 static int[] test(string criteria)
    {
        // criteria is 4012..4190|4229
        // select numbers from lab where criteria is met
        int[] lab = Enumerable.Range(0, 10000).ToArray();

        return lab;
    }
```

Comment: what effort have you already made?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be enough for your case:

```
return lab.Where((int1) => (int1 >= 4012 && int1 <= 4190) || int1 == 4229).ToArray();
```

Also a quick way of parsing your criteria would be to use RegEx:

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"\d+");
MatchCollection m = r.Matches(criteria);
int start = int.Parse(m[0].Value);
int end = int.Parse(m[1].Value);
int specific = int.Parse(m[2].Value);
return lab.Where((int1) => (int1 >= start && int1 <= end) || int1 == specific).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 3):

If your `criteria` is always a `string`, you need some way to parse it, to `Func<int, bool`, but it's not LINQ specific. In the end you'll need something like this:

```
Func<int, bool> predicate = Parse(criteria);
return lab.Where(predicate).ToArray();
```

where very basic implementation of `Parse` might look as follows:

```
public static Func<int, bool> Parse(string criteria)
{
    var alternatives = criteria
        .Split('|')
        .Select<string, Func<int, bool>>(
            token =>
            {
                if (token.Contains(".."))
                {
                    var between = token.Split(new[] {".."}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                    int lo = int.Parse(between[0]);
                    int hi = int.Parse(between[1]);
                    return x => lo <= x && x <= hi;
                }
                else
                {
                    int exact = int.Parse(token);
                    return x => x == exact;
                }
            })
        .ToArray();

    return x => alternatives.Any(alt => alt(x));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can concatenate two sequenses

```
int[] lab = Enumerable.Range(4012, 4190-4012).Concat(Enumerable.Range(4229,1)).ToArray();
```

*Update:*

you need to parse incoming criteria first

```
static int[] test(string criteria)
    {
        // criteria is 4012..4190|4229
        // select numbers from lab where criteria is met

        // assume you parsed your criteria to 2 dimentional array
        // I used count for second part for convience
        int[][] criteriaArray = { new int[]{ 4012, 50 }, new int[]{ 4229, 1 } };

        var seq = Enumerable.Range(criteriaArray[0][0], criteriaArray[0][1]);

        for (int i = 1; i < criteriaArray.Length; i++)
        {
            int start = criteriaArray[i][0];
            int count = criteriaArray[i][1];
            seq = seq.Concat(Enumerable.Range(start, count));
        }


        return seq.ToArray();
    }
```

Comment: BTW, you need to parse your criteria and substitute for respective numbers

Comment: works great but how the problem is that the criteria can look different from time to time like this:
4370|7010..7299|7331..7575|7691..7698

4480|7310|7610..7690
5180
and so on... How to go about this? How can I parse the criteria?

Comment: If you parse criteria to number pair array (start, count) or (start, end), you can concatenate your sequences in loop

Answer (score 0):

You could :
[Flatten[{Range[4012, 4190], 4229}]](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=4012..4190%7C4229)

And in some way this would work as well [4012..4190|4229](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=4012..4190%7C4229), but answer is exactly that - list of items from 4012 to 4190 and item 4229.

Lambda just imitates pure functions. However unless you have free wolfram kernel, using this approach might no be most cost effective. However, you do not need to write boilerplate code.